# throwing Class<? extends Throwable>

Tags: java, throwable

so I have a function which looks like this:

```java
    public void addExceptionCommands(Class<? extends Throwable> exClass, Command... commands) {
        for (Command command : commands) {

            try {
                //Push the command to the stack of executed commands
                executedCommands.push(command);
                command.execute();

            } catch (CouldNotExecuteCommandException e) {
                // Default strategy is to rollback
                rollback();
                // Log
                e.printStackTrace();
                //I want to throw exClass here
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to throw exClass, how to achieve this?
throw exClass does not work

EDIT:
Thanks guys for all of the answers, I ended up with using a Supplier :D

Comment: youre only passing a Class object, which is mainly useful for reflection. you should probably be passing a `Throwable` instead, so that it can actually be thrown

Comment: The parameter is a *type* of an exception. You have to throw an *instance* of an exception.

Comment: How about `throw exClass.newInstance(); `?

Comment: Ou I see, thank you guys :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only throw subclasses of `Throwable` and `Class` isnt.

However, you can modify your method to accept a supplier which generates a new Throwable which you then can throw:

```java
    public <T extends Throwable> void addExceptionCommands(Supplier<T> exceptionSupplier, Command... commands) throws T {
        for (Command command : commands) {
            try {
                //Push the command to the stack of executed commands
                executedCommands.push(command);
                command.execute();
            } catch (CouldNotExecuteCommandException e) {
                // Default strategy is to rollback
                rollback();
                // Log
                e.printStackTrace();
                //I want to throw exClass here

                final T exception = exceptionSupplier.get();
                exception.addSuppressed(e);

                throw exception;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can then call your method like so:

```java
addExceptionCommands(YourException::new, command1, command2, ...);
```

Comment: Here we're not so much suppressing the original exception as delivering it in an alternate form. It could make more sense to call `exception.initCause(e)` rather than `addSuppressed()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a class type, you can do something like

```
throw exClass.newInstance();
```

Comment: deprecated. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--

Comment: It's safer to pass in a `Supplier<? extends Throwable>`, rather than the class. This guarantees that it can be constructed (checked at compile time), whereas the class approach relies on there being a zero-arg constructor (checked at runtime).

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is a *type* of an exception. If you throw something, it has to be an *instance* of an exception.

I don't think this is going to work the way you think.

**If you want the caller to define the type of exception thrown, *then let the caller do so in its own code*.** A caller can catch the exception thrown by your method, and wrap it in any exception it chooses.

```
public void addExceptionCommands( Command... commands) 
throws CouldNotExecuteCommandException {
  ...
}

...
   try {
       commandable.addExceptionCommands( myCommands );
   } catch (CouldNotExecuteCommandException e) {
      // Wrap the command exception in my own.
      throw new MySpecialException( "My message", e );
   }
```

**If you want to support a variety of exceptions from the commands,** consider the example provided by Java's *java.util.concurrent* package. Consider `ExecutorService.submit()` methods, and the [`Future.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) method. The task submitted to the executor can throw a wide range of exceptions. But `Future.get()` wraps whatever exception was thrown in a single, well-defined, and declared `ExecutableException`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `java.lang.reflect.Constructor`

`Constructor.newInstance()` is better than `Class.newInstance()` because it allows you to use arguments to create the new instance.

```
Constructor constructor = exClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
Throwable ex = (Throwable) constructor.newInstance(); 
throw ex;
```

With `String` argument (for message?)

```
Constructor constructor = exClass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
Throwable ex = (Throwable) constructor.newInstance("message goes here"); 
throw ex;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Also, `Class.newInstance()` has been deprecated.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--